# Spring boot YAML Config not reading all values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I'm trying to setup and use a YAML as config file in my Spring Boot 1.5.1 project.

My YAML file looks like the following:

```
hue:
    user: cdKjsOQIRY8hqweAasdmx-WMsn
    ip: "http://192.168.1.69"
    scenes:
        sunstatus:
            enabled: true
            id: 93yv8JekmAneCU9
            group: 1
        disable:
            enabled: true
            id: 93yv8JekmAneCU9
            group: 6
```

It works perfectly fine to read hue.getUser(). However, hue.getScenes() returns null for some reason. My Java code for the Hue Config looks like the following:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hue")
public class Hue {
    private String user;
    private String ip;
    private Scenes scenes;

    /*
     * Getters and setters of course
     */

    public class Scenes {
        private Sunstatus sunstatus;
        private Disable disable;

        /*
         * Getters and setters
         */

        public class Sunstatus {
            private boolean enabled;
            private String id;
            private String group;

            /*
             * Getters and setters
             */
        }

        public class Disable {
            private boolean enabled;
            private String id;
            private String group;

            /*
             * Getters and setters
             */
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried as well to annotate the each class with prefix as well, both in the format of hue.scenes.sunstatus, scenes.sunstatus and just sunstatus as well.

Additionally I also tried to use the @Value annotation a bit without any luck.

It's the same results if I keep the data in application.yml or in an external file. Can always only reach getUser().

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using public non-inner classes for nested configuration, so you should add the `@NestedConfigurationProperty` instead:

```
public class Scenes {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Sunstatus sunstatus;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Disable disable;
```

> [Nested properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-nested-properties)
>
> You can use the @NestedConfigurationProperty annotation on a field to indicate that a regular (non-inner) class should be treated as if it were nested.

So either add the annotations (if you plan on using the classes elsewhere) or make them `public static`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but after switching to that I'm still having the same exact same issue.

Comment: Have you tried the making the classes public static, like the reference states, adding the correct getters/setters?

Comment: Yep made sure to try that again, but still null.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hue")
public class Hue {
    private String user;
    private String ip;
    private Scenes scenes = new Scenes();

    /*
     * Getters and setters of course
     */

    public class Scenes {
        private Sunstatus sunstatus = new Sunstatus();
        private Disable disable = new Disable();

        /*
         * Getters and setters
         */

        public class Sunstatus {
            private boolean enabled;
            private String id;
            private String group;

            /*
             * Getters and setters
             */
        }

        public class Disable {
            private boolean enabled;
            private String id;
            private String group;

            /*
             * Getters and setters
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scenes gets initialized now with those changes, but it it still returning null from example: hue.getScenes().getSunstatus().getId()

Comment: That is weird.It is OK for me.