# Springboot yaml config not reading boolean

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I'm new to Springboot. This is the problem I'm trying to solve. 
I've an application.yml file with the following property:

```
kinesis:
    streaming:
        client:
            featuretoggle:
                kinesisSenderFeature: true
```

I tried to access the value of the KinesisSenderFeature using the code:

```
@Value("${kinesis.streaming.client.featuretoggle.kinesisSenderFeature}")
private boolean featureToggle;
```

as well as

```
@Value("${kinesis.streaming.client.featuretoggle.kinesisSenderFeature}")
private Boolean featureToggle;
```

The PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean is defined as:

```
 @Bean
    @Primary
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
```

When I try to build, ApplicaitonContext fails to load with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMessageConsumer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'featureToggle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${kinesis.streaming.client.featuretoggle.kinesisSenderFeature}]
```

What I find weird is, it is trying to convert the string: *[${kinesis.streaming.client.featuretoggle.kinesisSenderFeature}]* into a boolean value, and I believe- is not reading the value of the property from the yaml file.

Yes, I did see:

- [Mapping list in Yaml to list of objects in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593014/mapping-list-in-yaml-to-list-of-objects-in-spring-boot?rq=1)
- [Spring boot YAML Config not reading all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145946/spring-boot-yaml-config-not-reading-all-values)
- [Evaluating spring @value annotation as primitive boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585259/evaluating-spring-value-annotation-as-primitive-boolean)

I don't want to create a bean around this property as this is just a boolean flag.

Note: If i put a :default in the @Value, the build succeeds- but I believe that is only because the read from yaml failed, and defaulted with the value I gave.

```
@Value("${kinesis.streaming.client.featuretoggle.kinesisSenderFeature:false}")
private boolean featureToggle;
```

Note: As pointed out by @Andreas in the comment, I tried giving

```
//In application.yml
kinesisSenderFeature:false

//In code
@Value("${kinesisSenderFeature}")
private boolean featureToggle;
```

Even that didn't work. But there are other properties that are read from the yaml without any problem. It is the standard application.yml that is in src/main/resources which I believe should be read by default?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For the sake of *researching* the problem, did you try defining a simple `abc: true` property and use that? You know, to see if any property is being read from that file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. No, even that didn't work. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Did you try without PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  bean. I mean remove this bean and see if the default PropertyReader from Spring picks it up properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pvpkiran pointed out, you do not need the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. Just put the `application.yml` on the classpath, Spring Boot picks it up and assigns the `Boolean`value. Works like a charm, just tested it with Spring Boot 1.5.2.